# Ruby on Rails / gem devise / login page in a modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to have the login page in a modal (instead of opening a separate page). I am using the gem devise to create account.
In views/layouts/application.html.erb, I created the code to call for the modal:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <%=render 'devise/sessions/newsession'%>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then in views/devise/sessions/_newsession.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I am getting the following error message:

> undefined local variable or method `resource' for <#:0x007fafd8bc60f8>

It looks like devise is not recognized in the page application.html.erb.

Would you understand where the error come from?

Answer (score 9):

As you're rendering the login form which uses a `resource` and `resource_name` variables which aren't initialized from "outside" a devise controller, what you can do is to add them to your ApplicationHelper file to be able to work with them from your current controller or any other.

Try editing your helper file adding the `resource`, `resource_name` and `devise_mapping`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
   @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

Just to add that if you want to render the sessions#new view file you can simply render this file as `render file: 'devise/sessions/new'`, if you've run the `devise:views` command, this would help you to maintain just one form instead creating a new one, of course, is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

1+ for Sebastians answer. Another way is pass the values to RenderingHelper:

```
<%= render 'layouts/modal/myModal', resource: User.new, resource_name: :user, devise_mapping: Devise.mappings[:user] %>
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Sebastian Palma's answer, you might need to add the following in your helper:

```
def resource_class
  User
end
```

So the entire addition in your application helper file will be:

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def resource_class
  User
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app)

I would've liked to post this as a comment to the actual post, but I don't have high enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Used this in the past, worked great:

```
 <div class="modal custom fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
           &times;       
         </button>
         <h2 class="text-center">Connexion</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">  
         <%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
           <div class="email-container">
             <%= f.text_field :email, :class =>"form-control",placeholder: "Email", value:"" %>
           </div>
           <div class="password-container">
             <%= f.password_field :password,:label =>"Password", :class =>"form-control", placeholder:"Password", value:""%>
           </div>
           <%= f.submit 'Login', :class =>"form-control" %>
           <%= f.check_box :remember_me, label: "Remember me", value: "true" %>
           <%= f.label :remember_me %>
         <% end %>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```